# Outlook 2010 Accepted Appointments showing as question marks

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, language, meeting-request

I have had several users approach me with an issue. Basically when viewing a meeting invitation with Japanese text the text displays fine. After accepting the invitation or trying to respond or Forward the meeting request the text turns to all question marks and the font is English Arial. I don't think Arial supports unicode by default and I believe this is what is causing the issue.

These systems are Windows 7 with both the Japanese and English languages installed.
It looks like Arial Unicode MS is installed on problem machines but I am not sure if additional texts need to be installed or any outlook settings need to be changed to overcome this issue.

It also looks like when viewing the properties of the accepted meeting request that the locale is en-US.
Here is the proprieties of the accepted, "bad" Meeting Request:

> Content-Language: en-US
>
> X-MS-Has-Attach:
>
> X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0

Here is a screenshot of the issue "in action".
[image: Invitations]

Does anyone have any insight into why this would happen and what I can do to mitiagte this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like the required font is missing.  I would verify your Outlook settings is using a font that exists on the system.

Comment: It appears to be the case that outlook is changing the font to Arial automatically and then I don't think that Arial can show the Japanese text.

Comment: So I guess you know what to do.  Change the font to something other then Arial.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your settings in outlook.

1. Click the orange "File" tab in the top left corner of the Outlook 2010 window and click "Options" on the pull-down menu. A new window titled "Outlook Options" appears.
2. Click the "Advanced" heading on the left side of the window and then scroll to the "International Options" heading near the bottom.
3. Place a check in the box labeled "Automatically select encoding for outgoing messages" and click "Unicode (UTF-8)" on the drop-down menu.
4. Place a check in the box labeled "Automatically select encoding for outgoing vCards" and click "Unicode (UTF-8)" on the drop-down menu.
5. Place a check in the box labeled "Allow UTF-8 support for the mailto: protocol."
6. Click "OK."

original solution found [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/setting-outlook-use-utf8-32242.html)